# Is there a way to map user names for LDAP in PAM?

Tags: ldap, login, pam

I'm managed to set up LDAP in PAM (linux). A problem I have is that many users have different user names in LDAP than on the local machine... Is there a way to map those user names (e.g. local name->LDAP name) or do I need to rename the user account on the local machine to get LDAP to work?

Answer (score 2):

They shouldn't have local accounts at all.  I thought that was the whole point of LDAP.

You can either rename their home directories to match their LDAP names, or specify their home directory path in LDAP's `homeDirectory` attribute.  Hopefully you've already got their `uidNumber`s set correctly in LDAP otherwise file permissions won't match up.

Comment: I only use LDAP for password verification (LDAP is used here mostly for our email system, so no homeDirectory AFAIK). It works great if the local user has the same login name as on LDAP (no problem with uidNumber)... just would like to not have to rename the user accounts.